# Relations in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

My Product model:

```
public function categoria(){
    return $this->belongsTo('estoque\Categoria');
}
```

and my model Categoria has:

```
public function produtos(){
        return $this->hasMany('estoque\Produto');
}
```

try to access from produto in the view `view`:

```
<td> {{$p->categoria}} <td>
```

Return an array:

```
{"id":1,"nome":"Cerveja","descricao":"Todas cervejas","ativo":1,"created_at":"2015-10-24 13:53:14","updated_at":"2015-10-24 13:53:14"}
```

This should not return an object of Categoria?
I would like to access like this:

```
<td> {{$p->categoria->nome}} <td>
```

not :

```
{{$p->categoria['nome']}}
```

But it is an array:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

But in the documentation the return is an object not array[Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many). Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using eager loading when loading your products? Try `$p = Product::with('categoria')->get()`

Comment: The return is always an object. How is your category id field named on the Product model?

Comment: @LuisDalmolin categoria_id

Comment: Didn't you use `toArray()` accidentally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to specify the local and foreign key in your relation.
Check this:

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships

You are forgetting write something like this:

```
return $this->hasMany('estoque\Produto', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

If you are not using convenctional ID names, you should specify it. In this case

```
return $this->hasMany('estoque\Produto', 'categoria_id', 'id');
return $this->belongsTo('estoque\Categoria', 'id', 'categoria_id');
```

Comment: Just `return $this->belongsTo('estoque\Categoria', 'categoria_id');` worked, edit your answer. Thanks man.