# Laravel Eloquent Relation Model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have 3 table on my database :

```
table 1 = user (hasMany order)
table 2 = order (hasMany order_detail, belongsTo user)
table 3 = order_detail (belongsTo order)
```

On my order_detail model i add this function :

```
public function order() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Order');
}
```

so i can call the order data without define it from controller, i just define order_detail on my controller

```
$order_detail->order->invoice_number
```

but how to call the user data from the order detail?

I try use this

```
$order_detail->order->user
```

but it didn't work for me..

Is there any idea to call the grand parent relation?

Comment: I think you could check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870287/relations-in-laravel-5

Comment: @luigonsec i already success for 2 table relation, but now to create for 3 tables?? $order_dettail->order->user->first_name

Comment: What you posted should work. Can you post the code (instead of psueo-code) on how you set your relationships?

Answer (score 0):

In order model add function for order_detail:

```
public function order_details() {
    return $this->hasMany('order_detail');
}
```

and for user:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('user');
}
```

In user model add:

```
public function orders() {
    return $this->hasMany('order');
}
```

Then, you can call in the controller:

```
$details = Order::find(1)->order_details->where('order_detail_id', 5)->first();
$userName = $details->username;
            //           ^
            // column name in order_detail table
```

More info in the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#one-to-many).

Comment: how to get user name from order_detail with id 5 for example?

Comment: I updated my answer, but I don't know what 'id' means. Is it order ID? You can change column name in where clausule.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the more complete way to define the relationships:

```
// User model

public function orders(){

    // I'm telling that users has many order. The orders have an user_id field that match with the ID field of the user.
    return $this->hasMany('App/Order', 'user_id' , 'id');

}


// Order model

public function order_details(){

    // I'm telling that order has many order_details. The order_details have an order_id field that match with the ID field of the order.
    return $this->hasMany('App/OrderDetail', 'order_id' , 'id');

}

public function user(){

    // I'm telling that an order belongs to an user. The user has an ID field that match with the order_id field of the order.
    return $this->belongTo('App/User', 'id', 'user_id');
}


// OrderDetail Model

public function order(){

    // I'm telling that an order detail belongs to an order. The order  has an ID field that match with the order_id field of the order detail.
    return $this->belongTo('App/Order', 'id', 'order_id');
}
```

I have seen that you put just the model name as first parameter in your relation definition. I think you must put the relative path from the root to the Model. In my case, I have the models as childs of the App folder.